# When I access the page first time, .is_valid return false

Tags: python, django

When I access the index page the first time, .is_valid return false. How can I make it not to show False message? Why it shows False when I access the page first time? Is there any way to avoid the False message?

urls.py is below

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = (
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

views.py is below

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import forms


def index(request):
    form = forms.Page1(request.GET or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        message = 'True'
    else:
        message = 'False'
    content = {
        'title': 'Webapp',
        'form': form,
        'message': message,
    }
    return render(request, 'forms.html', content)
```

forms.py is below

```
from django import forms

EMPTY_CHOICES = (
    ('', '-'*10),
)

GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('man', '男'),
    ('woman', '女')
)


class Page1(forms.Form):
    user_sir_name = forms.CharField(
        label='姓:',
        max_length=20,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(),
    )
    user_given_name = forms.CharField(
        label='名:',
        max_length=20,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(),
    )
    user_sex = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='性別:',
        widget=forms.Select,
        choices=EMPTY_CHOICES + GENDER_CHOICES,
        required=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# You will get False for the first time as you request the url, you are submitting nothing from your form and your fields are required to pass the input.

# So, change your views.py method and make your request to post


def index(request):
    form = forms.Page1(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        message = 'True'
    else:
        message = 'False'
    content = {
        'title': 'Webapp',
        'form': form,
        'message': message,
    }
    return render(request, 'forms.html', content)


and in your forms.html, change your form tag method to post


<form method="POST">
...
...
</form>
```

Comment: not only the first time, but he will also get the `False` always I presume

Comment: She just need to pass required fields input in the right manner from the forms, so that the form.is_valid() will return True.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the form error by using print(form.errors) after you have instanciated form. This will print the html error message in the command prompt. You can even pass this message to template to render.

```
def index(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
      form = forms.Page1(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          message = 'True'
      else:
          print(form.errors)
    else:
         print("you didn't post anything to form")
          message = 'False'
      content = {
       'title': 'Webapp',
       form': form,
       'message': message,
    }
    return render(request, 'forms.html', content)
```

Comment: Thanks your comment. 
`    if form.is_valid():
        message = 'True'
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        message = 'False'
    content = {
        'title': 'Webapp',
        'form': form,
        'message': message,
    }
`

But nothing print...

Comment: I see that means your form is empty. Try print(request.POST). If it doesnot have form feilds then nothing is being sent to django server to process.

Comment: I have added code to the answer, please check what you are getting. @kai00